# service iptables * doesn't display message

Tags: centos, iptables

Running `service iptables (start|stop|restart)` isn't displaying the usual `[FAILED]|[SUCCESS]` messages I'm used to on previous machines. This is a new server, but I've updated everything via `yum` (I'm running CentOS 6.2). This isn't really a problem, per se, but it's slightly bugging me. Anyone know what's up?

EDIT: Also, it seems I don't have an `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` This is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal for the case of a missing `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file. If you check the  `$?` exit code for `service iptables start | restart`  it will be `6`

```
# Do not start if there is no config file.
[ ! -f "$IPTABLES_DATA" ] && return 6
```

The `stop` function subsequently has nothing to do so just exit's with `0`

```
# Do not stop if iptables module is not loaded.
[ ! -e "$PROC_IPTABLES_NAMES" ] && return 0
```

So it's all good.

Comment: Well, I imported a `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` from one of my other servers, and like you said, that fixed it. Green checkmark for you! Thanks! However, isn't iptables supposed to manually generate that? Any idea why it didn't?

Answer (score 0):

`strace service iptables`, `getenforce` to see the SELinux and `id` to check you are root

Comment: or you could just read the /etc/init.d/iptables script and see what's happening.

Comment: I'd go `/bin/bash -x` before I launched straight into strace.